# Which is more Pythonic way?

Tags: python

I want to write a function to create an empty square matrix have size NxN.
I have 2 ways to write this:

1:

```
s_matrix = []
create_empty_square_matrix(s_matrix, N)
```

2:

```
s_matrix = empty_square_matrix(N)
```

(Ofcourse, 2 two functions will different a bit. Function create_empty_square_matrix is like a procedure - only manipulate on s_matrix. Function empty_square_matrix create & return a matrix)

Which way is more Pythonic & clearer?

Do you have some suggestions about naming style? I'm not sure about **empty_square_matrix** & **create_empty_square_matrix**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd always prefer the second way.

The problem with the first is that you pass the object that you want to write to as the paramenter (`s_matrix`), and the caller of the function will have to know that it must be passed an empty list. What happens if the caller passes a dict, or a list that is not empty?

By the way, if you want to do matrix calculations, you should take a look at the [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) library, it offers many things that standard Python does not.

Comment: Not only Pythonic, but in general - stateless, side-effect-free code is way better because it's not depending on a global state.